# Is there a parser/encoder for JavaScript object literals without the JSON-restrictions?

Tags: java, javascript, json

Well, following the "discussion" here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281903/java-json-parsers-whats-the-abusive-anal-thing-with-the-quote-marks-on-attribu

Is there a parser/decoder for JavaScript object literals without the JSON-restrictions?

**EDIT**

In my original post I did state that I work with a Java back end. I tagged it .net because I come from .net background and could use their support - and it proved to be right. They knew what I was talking about and with all the porting between the two languages - I was hoping to hear something new.

The Java back end needs both to read this "light" version of JSON, and to provide it.
So it's both Parser and Encoder. (I fixed the title name, sory for the confusion)

Comment: How about [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) that I suggested? Did you check it?

Comment: It rocks, but I have a Java team on the other end :(

Comment: So why is this question still tagged with `.net`? You should explicitly state that you are looking for a Java JSON serializer and retag your question.

Comment: You need to clarify what language environment you want the JSON tools to run in (that is, **Java** or **JavaScript** or something else), and whether you're specifically interested in **searializing** (generating JSON) or **deserializing** (turning JSON into native objects).

Comment: (Actually I guess the term "parser/decoder" probably means you want to deserialize JSON. One might wonder why you've got improper JSON in the first place, since generating it is a lot simpler than parsing it.)

Comment: Well YAML is sort-of a superset of JSON, and it (at least sometimes) doesn't require quotes around property names. If it were me I'd just write my own JSON parser; it's an extremely simple grammar, and having your own makes it easier to deal with object instantiation (during decode) to fit your application needs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That "abusive anal thing with the quote-marks on attribute names" as you call it, is a result of a decision made by Douglas Crockford to **greatly simplify the JSON format** and make writing JSON parsers **much easier**.

Remember that in JavaScript you can't have your object keys named: break, case, catch, class, const, continue, debugger, default, delete, do, else, enum, export, extends, false, finally, for, function, if, implements, import, in, instanceof, interface, let, new, null, package, private, protected, public, return, static, super, switch, this, throw, true, try, typeof, var, void, while, with and yield, unless they are quoted.

Also any key that is not a valid JavaScript identifier has to be quoted.

When you implement your "less anal" JavaScript object literals encoder and parser, remember to make exceptions for them, or otherwise **you wouldn't even have valid JavaScript object literals**.

#### UPDATE:

If you don't want to use quotes in your keys because you are so concerned with the network traffic overhead of using quotes that you'd rather roll your own JSON-like encoders and parsers that wouldn't use quotes instead of using the standard and tested JSON libraries (as I understand from your comments) then maybe **you shouldn't be using JSON in the first place**.

Maybe try some binary format like the [SDXF](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3072.html) (RFC 3072 – Structured Data Exchange Format) or [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/) (Binary JSON, a binary-encoded serialization of JSON-like documents) or roll your own **binary** format because removing quotes from JSON will not take you very far (maybe 1% for gzipped transfers at most).

#### UPDATE 2:

If I understand your situation correctly then you have JSON data like this one:

```
[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4},null,null,{"a":9,"b":10,"c":11,"d":12}]
```

It's 66 bytes. Converting it to plain JavaScript object literal it could be:

```
[{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4},,,{a:9,b:10,c:11,d:12}]
```

It's now 42 bytes. (Keep in mind that the handling of dangling commas is inconsistent between browsers – eg. `[1,,2,,]` is a **4**-element array in Firefox and probably 5-element array in IE.)

But this is not everything you can do. You can remove colons, curly braces and commas in objects:

```
a1b2c3d4,,,a9b10c11d12
```

It's 22 bytes now. It's about **half** of the version without quotes and **one third** of the version with quotes, and it's still easy to parse. If you have a flat data structure then it may be fine for you. I'll call this new format that I have just invented **CFON** for Compact Flat Object Notation.

You could convert it to JSON using code like this:

```
var inp = input.split(','),
    out = [], i, j, m, p, output;
for (i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
    if (inp[i]) {
        out[i] = {};
        m = inp[i].match(/[a-z]+\d+/ig);
        for (j = 0; j < m.length; j++) {
            p = /([a-z]+)(\d+)/i.exec(m[j]);
            out[i][p[1]] = p[2];
        }
    }
}
output = JSON.stringify(out);
```

See [CFON→JSON DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3NDwG/).

And you can convert JSON to this small format using code like this:

```
var inp = JSON.parse(input),
    out = [], i, k, output;
for (i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
    out[i] = '';
    if (inp[i]) {
        for (k in inp[i]) {
            if (inp[i].hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                out[i] += k + inp[i][k];
            }
        }
    }
}
output = out.join(',');
```

See [JSON→CFON DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FRvT9/).

Now that I'm thinking about it I might add support for decimal fractions and make a CFON library. If anyone would be interested please comment.

Anyway, this is still just a text format. If you go binary you will have better results especially for large numbers. Also if you have a list of predefined keys then it's easy to use numbers for each of them. If keys are numbers and values are numbers then it can be very compact in binary.

Comment: Good point (voted up:) ). Since all my attribute names are predefined (none-of-which are key-words) I guess I'm going on a more customized specified version. But I was hoping I can have a good start to extend, and not start from scratch...

However - the decision to simplify JSON parsing helped JSON up, but I think that now that it's there - it should move on and adopt to the terms of the present - where the barricade is not parsing, but network.

Comment: @Radagast: I'm just curious, how does your data look like that quoting keys make so much difference in the network traffic that you are willing to roll your own format, with your own encoders and parsers, instead of using the standard JSON libraries that are available for virtually every language?

Comment: Attribute names up to 4 characters, values are mainly numbers. Nested in arrays, in which false/null values are just skipped. Same setting is used for network and for configurations. The bold example - The current configuration file is 21K without commas and 35K with commas. However - the configuration is just read once per application life time. The transport is for every user 4 times a minuet. That's a lot.

Comment: @Radagast: In that situation you are right that you want to get rid of as much overhead as possible. If I were you I would go for a binary format, either BSON if it is good enough for you or using some custom encoding. Also see another update to my answer with some ideas of a compact text format for flat JSON structures.

Comment: I've gone as far as you describe, but decided to leave it for a later optimization phase: Attribute names are not final for extensibility reasons - the system still develops and extends, however yet intends to go to beta stage of _hi_ loads. Since communication between client and server is still HTTP calls of browser - it was decided to stop on Object-Literals as the trade-off point of loads, readability, extensibility and such, and implement the more compact protocol after the functional spec stabilizes. P.S - Until today I did not make the distinction between JSON and Object-Literals.